# Nuget pack 3.4.3 csproj + project.json include dependencies

Tags: c#, nuget, project.json

I am trying to change packages.config into `csproj + project.json`
 for managing nuget packages. I've noticed one important change - when using `nuget pack` it's excluding all dependencies by default while with packages.config it was including them unless `developmentdependency=true` attribute was set. How can I achieve the same functionality? I mean generating dependencies on the fly. project.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "EPPlus": "4.0.4",
    "Excel": "2.1.0.0",
    "log4net": "1.2.10.0",
    "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel": "11.0.0.1"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "net451": {}
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win-anycpu": {},
    "win": {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been fixed in 3.5.0-beta2 release of nuget which can be downloaded here:
https://dist.nuget.org/index.html